# Explicit template static member instantiation in a derived class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, inheritance, singleton

I am trying to implement a template class with a static member. Classes that are derived from the template class shall be instantiated without the need to write extra code.

Here is my naive (and not successful) approach:

*Singleton.h:*

```
template <class T> class Singleton {
protected:
  Singleton();
  static T instance_;
}

// explicit instantiation of 'instance_' ???, 
// where 'instance_' is an instance of the derived class
template <class T> T Singleton<T>::instance_;
```

*ConcreteA.h:*

```
class ConcreteA : public Singleton<ConcreteA> {
public:
  ConcreteA();
  void foo();
}
```

*main.c:*

```
int main() {
  // an instance of ConcreteA should have been created (no extra code)!!!
  return 0;
}
```

**Is there a way to force the instantiation of `ConcreteA` by just deriving `ConcreteA` from `Singleton`, without writing extra instantiation code?**

A *dirty workaround* is to call an method on `instance_` in the `ConcreteA` constructor, for example:

*ConcreteA.c*

```
ConcrereA::ConcreteA { instance_.foo(); }
```

**Are there better workarounds?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building upon your own "dirty trick", this works in all the compilers I tested, and doesn't require any code in the derived class constructor:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T> class Singleton {
protected:
  Singleton() { instptr_ = &instance_; }
  static T instance_;
private:
  static T* instptr_;
};

template<class T> T Singleton<T>::instance_;
template<class T> T* Singleton<T>::instptr_;

class ConcreteA : public Singleton<ConcreteA> {
public:
  ConcreteA() { std::cout << "ConcreteA constructed.\n"; }
  void foo();
};

int main() {
  //Prints 'ConcreteA constructed.'.
  return 0;
}
```

My understanding of it is that taking the address of `instance_` *odr-uses* it, forcing it into existence. I must say I'm not 100% sure this is guaranteed not to be optimized away in future versions of some compiler (I tested it with `-O2` everywhere).

EDIT: Looks like even writing the base class constructor like this

```
Singleton() { (void)&instance_; }
```

is enough, which gets rid of `instptr_` altogether.

Comment: Yes, casting to `void` seems the smallest possible solution here. It is a common way to get rid of unfixable "variable/parameter unused" warnings.

Comment: @BartoszKP Yeah, that occurred to me immediately after I wrote the first variant, but I decided I'd leave the first one in there as well, as it looks slightly less likely to be optimized away (I still have doubts about this part, with all the 'whole program / link-time optimizations' that compilers use these days).

Comment: Is there a way to make the `ConcreteA` constructor `protected`?

Comment: @sergej You'd have to add `friend Singleton<ConcreteA>;` to the definition of `ConcreteA`. That'll do it, since the initialization of `instance_` is in the context of `Singleton<T>`, which now has access to the protected constructor.

Comment: This works in VS 2019.  It might be the only answer in the world that works.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, that is not possible. Quoting C++11 14.7.1/2 (talking about implicit instantiation of templates):

> Unless a member of a class template or a member template has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly
>   specialized, the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced
>   in a context that requires the member definition to exist; **in particular, the initialization (and any associated
>   side-effects) of a static data member does not occur unless the static data member is itself used in a way
>   that requires the definition of the static data member to exist.**

Answer (score 0):

it's done this way:

```
template <class T> class Singleton {
protected:
  Singleton();

  // note: static function contains static variable
  static T& instance() {
    static T _t; // c++11 guarantees that this is thread-safe
    return _t;
  }
}

class ConcreteA : public Singleton<ConcreteA>
{
  ...
};

auto& myA = ConcreteA::instance();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer: `auto& myA = ConcreteA::instance();` is the line I am trying to avoid.

Comment: In all but the most convoluted of cases it's a mistake to avoid this line - you're setting users up for a fall.

Answer (score -2):

In C++ static object are guarantee to initialize just if a code from the file that the instance is defined has been called (The order of the initialization is not guarantee).

because of this it better do instance the object inside a function and than call the function

```
class A{
public:
    static A& getInstance(){
       static A a;
       return a;
    }
protected:
    A(){
    }
};
```

Comment: @user2139223 It compiles now, but still: 1) is wrong (usually you don't want to copy a singleton, and your `getInstance` does it). 2) even leaving that aside it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I answered the question in the first part, I'm sorry if I didn't been clear enough